# Angular i18n - dynamically load translation

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization, angular-i18n

I need to asynchronously load the translation for my Angular app. I'm trying to utilize `loadTranslations` function from `@angular/localize` module. The problem is that it only works if I put it to `polyfills.ts` file at the bottom. I need to load this data using ajax request so I wanted to delay bootstrapping the app until that. Here is the code from `main.ts`

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import '@angular/localize/init';

import { loadTranslations } from '@angular/localize';

// delay from ajax call
setTimeout(() => {
  loadTranslations({
    'test': '123'
  });

  if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
  
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}, 1000);
```

The app starts without an error but translations are not applied. It also doesn't work if I remove async delay:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import '@angular/localize/init';

import { loadTranslations } from '@angular/localize';

loadTranslations({
  'test': '123'
});

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

But it works if I move i18n code to `polyfills.ts` (only synchronous version)

```
import '@angular/localize/init';

import { loadTranslations } from '@angular/localize';

loadTranslations({
  'test': '123'
});
```

And here is a sample template

```
<p i18n="@@test">Not working</p>
```

Why it only works with `polyfills.ts` and doesn't work with `main.ts` and is there a way to initialize it asynchronously?